# time difference calculation in between current time and previously saved time

Tags: php, time

**Description:**
I wrote the following function to calculate the differenece between two times.. It shows a very funny and strange calculation some times ... Sometimes it works perfect.. What is wrong with this code?

**PHP**

```
function get_the_time_of_post($datetime1,$datetime2)
{
$month =  date("F",strtotime($datetime1));
$day = date("d",strtotime($datetime1));
$a = new DateTime($datetime1);
$b = new DateTime($datetime2);
$interval = $a->diff($b);

$hours = $interval->format("%H");
$seconds = $interval->format("%S");
$days = $interval->format("%D");
$minutes = $interval->format("%I");

$date_statement_return = $month." , ".$day;
if($days == 0)
{
    if($hours == 0)
    {
        if($minutes == 0)
        {
            if($seconds >= 0 && $seconds <=30)
            {

                $date_statement_return = $date_statement_return." <span style = 'font-size: 12px;'> moment ago</span>";
            }
            else 
            {
                $date_statement_return = $date_statement_return."<span style = 'font-size: 12px;'> ".$seconds." secs ago </span>";
            }
        }

        else if ($minutes >= 1 && $minutes <= 59)
        {
            $date_statement_return = $date_statement_return."<span style = 'font-size: 12px;'> ".$minutes." mins ago </span>";
        }
    }

    else if ($hours >= 1 && $hours <24)
    {
        $date_statement_return = $date_statement_return."<span style = 'font-size: 12px;'> ".$hours." hrs ago </span>";
    }

}

else if ($days > 0 && $days < 3)
{
    if($days == 1)
    {
        $date_statement_return = $date_statement_return."<span style = 'font-size: 12px;'> yesterday </span>";
    }
    else
    {
        $date_statement_return = $date_statement_return."<span style = 'font-size: 12px;'> ".$days." days ago </span>";
    }
}
return $date_statement_return;
}
```

Comment: `It shows a very funny and strange calculation some times` You need to do more than just say that. *Show* us how it returns incorrect values. How else are we supposed to know what's wrong?

Comment: @JohnConde By that I meant random changes in the out put every time you run the function ... thats why I wrote "perfect some times. M sorry was I suppose to show examples??

Comment: Yes, examples are helpful for diagnosing the problem. You should show examples that work and examples that do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using format characters that returns values with leading zeros. This makes doing comparison with other numbers awkward and prone to errors.

```
$hours   = $interval->format("%h");
$seconds = $interval->format("%s");
$days    = $interval->format("%d");
$minutes = $interval->format("%i");
```

Comment: So that was the problem ?? my conditional statements and there nesting is correct ??

Comment: This looks like the problem but I can't tell since I don't have any examples of what works and what doesn't work. Test it out and let us know what happens.